# Python SSL error CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, ssl

I have issue with requests to my school's website. I have searched online for the solution, while none of them works for me. I have installed certifi through pip, it doesn't work. I have reinstalled openssl, but it doesn't work.

```
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017'
```

Specifically, the SSL verification is the problem here. I can open the web page with my browser correctly without any warning with SSL, but I can't do with Python.

So, what should I do next? Hope someone can give me a little bit advices. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading the Python's `requests` [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/),

I found the following, which stated :

> When you are using the prepared request flow, keep in mind that it
>   does not take into account the environment. This can cause problems if
>   you are using environment variables to change the behaviour of
>   requests. For example: **Self-signed SSL** certificates specified in
>   `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` will not be taken into account. As a result an
>   `SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` is thrown. You can get around this
>   behaviour by explicity merging the environment settings into your
>   session:
>
> ```
> from requests import Request, Session
>
> s = Session()
> req = Request('GET', url)
>
> prepped = s.prepare_request(req)
>
> # Merge environment settings into session
> settings = s.merge_environment_settings(prepped.url, None, None, None, None)
> resp = s.send(prepped, **settings)
>
> print(resp.status_code)
> ```

*I recommend to read the docs because I just quoted a part of the original documentation.*

Other than that,

> Requests verifies SSL certificates for HTTPS requests, just like a web
>   browser. By default, SSL verification is enabled, and Requests will
>   throw a SSLError if it's unable to verify the certificate.

You can use `verify` parameter to provide the path to a `CA_BUNDLE` file or directory with certificates of trusted CA's:

```
>>> requests.get('https://your-school-website-url.com', verify='/path/to/cacert_file')
```

`Requests` can also **ignore** verifying the ***SSL certificate*** if you set `verify` to `False`:

```
>>> requests.get('https://kennethreitz.org', verify=False)
<Response [200]>
```

**By default**, `verify` is set to `True`. Option verify only applies to host certs.

Again, kindly read the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/).

### **Hope it helps !**

Comment: I am sorry, I think I didn't interpret my problem clearly. This is not about requests package, my request through urllib.request.urlopen also fails due to the same problem. I wish I could find a more general solution to this

Comment: Have you tried `urllib2.urlopen(req, cafile="cacert_file")` ?

Comment: I don't have the location of a ca file on my Mac. I wanted to fix it which requires no suffix to the function. It's actually done by me reinstalling the python 3.5

Comment: Glad to hear that !